# why the height and width of the button in applet java is not changed using setBounds() method?

Tags: java, layout, applet, awt

method `setBounds(x, y, width, height)` to change the position of the button is worked but width and height is not changed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class ButtonDemo extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    public void init() {
        setBounds(0, 30, 30, 60);
        Button yes = new Button("Yes");
        add(yes);
        yes.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the bounds of the button itself you need to apply it to the Button object:

```
Button yes = new Button("Yes");
yes.setBounds(0, 30, 30, 60);
```

What you're doing now only changes the bounds of the container, not the button.

EDIT: I'm not sure `setBounds()` is even supposed to work for a JButton. You should use `JButton.setLocation()` and `JButton.setSize()` instead.

SECOND EDIT: You should look at [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead of using the `setBounds()`, `setLocation()`, or `setSize()` methods. It will be much easier and more stable.

Comment: it is not changed bro, I use yes.setBounds(), but not changed :(

Comment: Please see my edits, thanks. I posted before I really looked into the problem =P

Answer (score 0):

You must set the layout of your applet in order to size buttons added to it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class ButtonDemo extends Applet implements ActionListener {


    public void init() {
        setLayout(null)
        Button yes= new Button("Yes");
        yes.setBounds(0,30,30,60);


        add(yes);
        yes.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {

    }
}
```

Although I HIGHLY suggest you looking into the layouts Oracle has provided you, but if you just want to set bounds, you can set layout to null

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you shouldn't.  The position and size of the a component should be based on the requirements of the layout manager (which is why your button doesn't change).

While it might seem like a good idea to try and do away with layout managers, you will spend more of your time trying to correct for all things that go wrong then actually writing your code.

Layout managers make it possible to define user interfaces that run across multiple platforms with different font metric requirements, DPI and rendering pipelines, all of which can change the amount of space a component might need to render possible.

Swing is designed to use layout manager.  Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details and ideas